# VBA - Concatenate columns on the first column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to concatenate columns but in the first column in VBA, like that :

```
A         | B         | C         |
sentence1 | sentence2 | sentence3 |
sentence4 | sentence5 | sentence6 |
sentence7 | sentence8 | sentence9 |
```

->

```
A                             | B       | C      
sentence1 sentence2 sentence3 | nothing | nothing
sentence4 sentence5 sentence6 | nothing | nothing
sentence7 sentence8 sentence9 | nothing | nothing
```

How can I do ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim tempval As String

Dim row As Integer, col As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'loop through rows
For row = 1 To 3 Step 1

    'clear temp string
    tempval = ""

    'loop through columns
    For col = 1 To 3 Step 1

        'save columnvalues in temp
        tempval = tempval & Cells(row, col).Value

        'delete cell value
        Cells(row, col).Value = ""
    Next col

    'paste saved string into first cell
    Cells(row, 1).Value = tempval
Next row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1):

the following does what you ask and is a little more generic in that:

- it takes into account all cells of column "A" with some text in it
- it extends the range whose content is to be concatenated to all consecutive non blank cells in the given row

in other words this approach doesn't suffer neither from any possible variations of columns number to consider (they can be 3, as per your example, or more or less) nor from the condition of having all rows having the same number of cells filled

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim cell As Range

With Worksheets("mySheet").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
    For Each cell In .Cells
        cell.Value = Join(Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(Range(cell, cell.End(xlToRight)))))
        Range(cell.Offset(, 1), cell.End(xlToRight)).Clear
    Next cell
    .WrapText = False
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already solved the solution before you wrote this. Sorry !

Comment: You're welcome. You mat want to post your solution so as to have other user benefit from it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim r As Range
For Each r In Sheet1.UsedRange
   r(1, 1).Value = r(1, 1).Value & " " & r(1, 2).Value & " " & r(1, 3).Value
   r(1, 2).Value = ""
   r(1, 3).Value = ""
Next r
```

Comment: shouldnt you add a '.row' in the for..each loop?

Comment: No, because we're working with ranges here rather than ListRows.